# how to create json array dynamically from the database

Tags: database

I have a table which contains first name and last name of some employees.Now my question is how to dynamically create a json array like :

```
"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
```

]

Comment: which language are you working in?

Comment: java script for client side and php for server side

Answer (score 0):

psuedocode

```
rows= query("select firstName,lastName from employees")

array a=[] //initialize empty array
for (index,row) in rows
    set a[index]=array('firstname'=>row.firstname,'lastname'=>row.lastname)
end for
b= json_encode(a)
```

Php implementation

```
//in php connect to database
$result = mysql_query("select firstName,lastName from employees");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$a=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
     $a[]=$row;
}
$b=json_encode($a);
echo $b;
```

Comment: @rahul did this answer your question?

Comment: Now, how can i access 2nd row to $b ?

can i use $b[2]

Comment: $b is a json encoded "string", but you can do $a[2] if you want to access the 2nd row